# How to show products with the most quantity sorted first

Tags: stock

Prior to my store allowing back orders, when browsing all products that were "In Stock" were displayed with a higher priority over products that were "Out of stock".

Since allowing back orders on my website, now the logic for this functionality is flawed. Now products with 0 stock are mixed with products with stock making it difficult for visitors to find products that are available for immediate purchase.

What I would like to do is show products with the most quantity first and not just "In Stock"

I'm finding plenty of information about sorting products by "in stock" but nothing about product quantities.

**What is the best method to achieve sorting products by the largest quantities first when browsing?**

Comment: Do you have only simple products in your shop or configurable and bundle also?

Comment: @Marius yes all products in the store are simple products.

Comment: Then you can try what Richard answer. I will also try to find a solution myself also.

Comment: Please advise how to sort stock from decending to asending for magento 2.3 Version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147417)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I got.
The following code works for simple products with manageable stock only. It all falls over if configurable, grouped or products for which you don't manage the stock are involved.
You will need a new extension, just like Richard also suggested that rewrites the product collection resource model.
Here is the full extension. Let's name it `Easylife_Sorting`.
You will need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Sorting.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sorting>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Sorting>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_collection>Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sorting/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` - the rewritten collection model

```
<?php
class Easylife_Sorting_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection {
    public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC){
        //don't screw up the admin sorting
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID){
            return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        }
        //the stock sorting should apply only when sorting by position. Leave the price and name alone
        if ($attribute == 'position') {
            //join the stock status index table for the current website and check if the product is saleable and the qtu.
            $select = $this->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
                'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
                array(
                    'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
                    'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
                )
            );
            //get the reversed sorting
            //if by position ascending, then you need to sort by qty descending and the other way around
            $reverseDir = ($dir == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            //this is optional - it shows the in stock products above the out of stock ones independent if sorting by position ascending or descending
            $this->getSelect()->order('salable DESC');
            //sort by qty
            $this->getSelect()->order('qty '.$reverseDir);
            return $this;
        }
        //if not sorting by position, let magento do its magic.
        return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, here you're directly manipulating the select object, rather than using the collection methods, would you explain why? Is related to things like this http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/339 ?

Comment: @Richard. The idea is not actually mine. Magento does the same thing to hide the out of stock products. Take a look at the method `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Status::addStockStatusToSelect`. I found that by mistake and realized that is a good approach to filter products by stock status or sort them by stock status. It also applies on this case.

Comment: Oh, well if it's ok to beat the Select up manually, I've revised mine to count up the stock in configurable. :)

Comment: @Richar...well, you kind of do the same thing...manipulate the select with `$this->getSelect()->columns` :).

Comment: It appears to only work if the sorting is done by "Position" - is this the intention ? The other sorting methods of Price and Manufacturer do not sort by qty's. Any thoughts? THANK YOU MARIUS :)

Comment: Yes. The script was intended to work only for position. If the user wants to sort by price or name, let him see the products like he wants. It's really bad user experience to sort alphabetical and see a different sorting.  but if you insist, just remove `if ($attribute == 'position') {` from my code and `return $this;`. But what's the point in having  sorting options if you are going to show the products as you want anyway?

Comment: I see what you are saying; From what I've observed in my scenario is that visitors do not purchase products without stock. So if I present them only products with stock then it *should* help conversion. Here is your bounty :) http://candyaddict.com/blog/candy_images/bounty_bar_wrapped.jpg

Comment: Thanks...but the link says 404 bounty not found.

Comment: Its a link to a picture of the "bounty" candy bar :)

Comment: I thought it was that. But I can't see the image. I'm getting a 404 error. But a thumbs up for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code it will sort the product collection based on the inventory Quantity.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inventory_table'=>'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id ",
            array('qty')
        )->order(array('_inventory_table.qty DESC'));
```

You can change the **DESC** to **ASC** to do the reverse

Answer (score 1):

We have an un elegant solution but it works for us. We have created a new attribute called category_sort_score. We then run a nightly cron that updates this value based on the products stock level , backorder value , popularity ,  etc. We then use this attribute as the default sort for categories. This is not an ideal solution but it seems to do the trick. The complications are however , grouped products , configurable products and bundled products as their stock level is dependant on their children.

Comment: That's an interesting solution and I will consider it but for now I'll wait to see if anyone else chimes in. You would think that this would be a feature that went a long with the back order's.

Comment: Creating a new attribute just to sort the products isn't really a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 3**

*This now works for configurable products, if by works you mean counts up the total for all the child products*

We redefined position sort to do this. We created a subcless of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and overrode `addAttributeToSort` in an extension, I won't go into creating your own extension and using your subclass instead of the normal one here, but our replacement `addAttributeToSort` is this.

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
    if ($attribute == 'position') {
        $orig_dir = $dir;
        $dir = ($dir == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $atts = array();
        if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
            $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir);
            return $this;
        }
        $entity_type_id = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product')->getEntityTypeId();
        $attribute_id = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'status');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array(
                'css1' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
            ),
            'e.entity_id = css1.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
            ''
        )->joinLeft(
            array(
                'cpsl' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')
            ),
            'cpsl.parent_id = e.entity_id',
            ''
        )->joinLeft(
            array(
                'css2' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
            ),
            'css2.product_id = cpsl.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
            ''
        )->joinLeft(
            array(
                'cpei' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'
            ),
            "cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id AND cpei.entity_type_id = $entity_type_id and attribute_id = $attribute_id",
            ''
        )->where(
            '(cpei.value IS NULL or cpei.value=' . Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED . ')'
        )->group(
            'e.entity_id'
        );

        if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
            $atts[] = "qty_position {$dir}";
        } else {
            // optimize if using cat index
            $this->addPriceData();
            $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
            if (isset($filters['category_id']) || isset($filters['visibility'])) {
                $atts[] = 'qty_position ' . $dir;
            } else {
                $atts[] = 'e.entity_id ' . $dir;
            }
        }
        $atts[] = "max_price {$orig_dir}";
        $this->getSelect()->columns(array('qty_position' => new Zend_Db_Expr ("IF(`e`.`type_id` = 'simple', `css1`.qty + position, sum(css2.qty) + position)")));
        $this->getSelect()->order($atts);
    } elseif ($attribute == 'price' && Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() != 0) {
        $this->addPriceData();
        $this->getSelect()->order("price_index.max_price {$dir}");
    } else {
        parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It's slightly more complicated than you asked for, it sorts by (position + qty) in reverse, and then max_price forwards. Eg. If you chose `position asc` in the list page tool bar the collection is sorted by (position + qty) in descending order, and then max price asc.

We use position in our categories backwards, so 0 appears last and 1000 would appear first, and we let this combine with qty so we can use position to keep products with no stock at the top if we need to.

We sort by max_price not min_price because we didn't like products being ordered by their tier pricing, but if you're making heavy use of special price you may want to cut that bit.

The only bit I can't remember the why for is `{{table}}.stock_id=1` which you might need to investigate.

Comment: But does this work for configurable products? They don't have a qty on their own.

Comment: No. Sorry, I saw you comment to the question and did mean to qualify that it was only for simples, making it work for configurables is on our TODO list

Comment: @Richard where do I insert this code?

Comment: Create an extension, create a model that extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection and overrides addAttributeToSort with the code, there's quite a few answers on here that deal with that aspect of your question.

Comment: Small fix; add 'cpei' in front of attribute_id, so `and attribute_id =` becomes `and cpei.attribute_id = `, otherwise you'll get ambiguous attribute_id in query warnings.

Comment: Oh? with the code as above? I can't see which other table would have an attribute_id, not that disambiguating it would hurt.